# Transaction fails due to: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: transactions, ethereum

I am trying to make transactions on Polygon Mainnet, but unfortunately when I automatically try to calculate the transaction fees, the transaction gets reverted because I assume that the fees are to low. Here is what I automatically generate:

```
{
'data':'0xf0f63daddb56b93eae180d01fea3e85f986af747f3903959afd249061e871d35a11417fa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064d017e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
'gas'      : 169986
 'maxFeePerGas': 191060633150
 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 30000000000
 'nonce'    : 54
 'to'       : '0x38f1CAd3B8Ee3a93Dd3aE30bb5f0Df900f05771F'
 }
```

That is why I tried to manually adjust the values to:

```
{
 'data'     : '0xf0f63dad94a098029154d1664f2565f762099c82ec54ef69af8eb06252147950c0e82cf80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064d017e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
 'gas'      : 169986
 'maxFeePerGas': 169307244988
 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 30000000000
 'nonce'    : 54
 'to'       : '0x38f1CAd3B8Ee3a93Dd3aE30bb5f0Df900f05771F'
}
```

However with those new values, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Can you advise me what should I change in order to be sure that the transaction always succeeds. The wallet which pays the transaction fees has always enough balance.